# Problem with creating my first react project npx npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I keep getting these errors all the time

I'm trying to create my first react app and it doesn't work

these are the errors that I'm getting :

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run


npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-13T11_44_07_216Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Tell us the command that you have used and by which you have got his error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that I'm creating a react app the wrong way

I used to write the `create react app` without an 'e' at the end of the word create

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32925420)

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
npm install
```

This worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).